# Generating Numbers/Text in certain way/form

Tags: python, random, key, generate

Working on a script to generate a Key of letters/numbers in a certain way, I need to generate the key  in a format like shown here  `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx`, i would generate the key in replace of the `xxxx-xxxx-xxxx` like `19n3-m1m9-1nl1` but then generate this key in front of another string like `Key=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx` so `Key=19n3-m1m9-1nl1` and loop it multiple times then save this string in a text file

Comment: `'Key={}{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}'.format(*'19n3m1m91nl1')` gives `'Key=19n3-m1m9-1nl1'`

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide more detail I'll be able to answer your question better, but here is how I would achieve what I **think** it is you're attempting:

1: Import relevant modules

```
import random, string
```

2: Generate random string of 16 letters / digits. Note this will not evenly distribute numbers/letters throughout the key like the example you gave - please let me know if this is a requirement.

```
key = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits, k=16))
```

3: "Join" groups of 4 characters with a dash.

```
key = '-'.join([key[:4], key[4:8], key[8:12], key[12:16]])
```

4: Lastly, add "Key=" to the start of the string:

```
key = "Key=" + key
```

5: Example output:

```
'Key=ed2o-kn7o-jyif-18wo'
```

You can save this to a text file using:

```
text_file = open("keys.txt", "w")
text_file.write(key)
text_file.close()
```